# Anyone else have success setting up the Brave Browser Sync on OSX?

Tags: ios, macos

I just installed Brave on my iPhone and my Macbook. I'm trying to set up Sync between the two, but the instructions given by Brave show:

[image]

Although when I click the hamburer menu on my Brave install on my Macbook there is no "Brave Sync" option anywhere in the menu, or anywhere in the settings for that matter.

Am I crazy? How do I set this thing up? Any help super appreciated!

Comment: Have you talked to Brave about how to do this with their software?  That will be your best approach.